# Looking for react component for inline (live) translations

Tags: javascript, react, translation

I am looking for solution to create inline translation similar to that one [from magento 1](https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/magento-tutorials/magento-tutorial-how-to-enable-inline-translation). I was faced with that for many years, but this days we decided to move `magento 1` to something more modern.

Have you ever met any react component (or any js package) which solve same problem? What I want to achieve is create possibility to edit translations on "live" page.

Would be nice if it will work with react-i18n, but its not necessary.